# ProfileRequiredActionFilter - permanently redirecting user

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have an implementation of ProfileRequiredActionFilter. It checks if user does have profile filled properly - if not, it redirect user on RegisterSecondStep.

The problem is that this redirecting permanently user in loop..

```
public class ProfileRequiredActionFilter : IActionFilter
{
    #region Implementation of IActionFilter

    public void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        if (HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            User user = UserTools.getUser(HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name);
            if (user.NickName == null || user.Firstname == null || user.Surname == null || user.StateId == 0)
            {
                filterContext.Result = new RedirectResult("/Account/RegisterSecondStep");
            }
        }
    }

    public void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext filterContext)
    {
    }

    #endregion
}
```

I added this part in my code - now user is redirecting once to RegisterSecondStep, and it is not allowed to do anything. Generally - nice. But how to allow user to logout? This buttons is also blocked, and if I click on "logout" I have been redirect to.. `RegisterSecondStep`.

```
public class ProfileRequiredActionFilter : IActionFilter
{
    #region Implementation of IActionFilter

    public void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        string text = HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.AbsolutePath;
        if (HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            User user = UserTools.getUser(HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name);
            if (user.NickName == null || user.Firstname == null || user.Surname == null || user.StateId == 0)
            {
                if (text != "/Account/RegisterSecondStep")
                {
                    filterContext.Result = new RedirectResult("/Account/RegisterSecondStep");
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext filterContext)
    {
    }

    #endregion
}
```

This is how I run this filter

```
    public static void RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilterCollection filters)
    {
        filters.Add(new HandleErrorAttribute());
        filters.Add(new ProfileRequiredActionFilter());
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know how you apply that attribute to action but you shouldn't apply that attribute for actions like RegisterSecondStep or Signout. Just inherit from `ActionFilterAttribute`.

```
public class ProfileRequiredAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        // your logic
    }
}
```

and apply that attribute to controller:

```
[ProfileRequired]
public class SomeController : Controller
{
}
```

or action:

```
public class SomeController : Controller
{
    [ProfileRequired]
    public ActionResult Index() 
    {
    }
}
```

Another option is to provide another attribute that override that behavior and in your `ProfileRequiredActionFilter` check if that attribute was applied to action.

```
if (filterContext.ActionDescription.IsDefined(typeof(ProfileNotRequiredAttribute), inherit: false))
{
    // do not redirect
}
```

That way was used in [AuthorizeAttribute](http://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#src/System.Web.Mvc/AuthorizeAttribute.cs).

Comment: Ok, so please tell me how to shouldn't apply that filter for these actions. I added a `RegisterGlobalFilters` code in my first post. Regards!